# How to center a div in the middle of a background image with size contain?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a background image with size set to contain:

```
background: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/404.svg') no-repeat center center;
background-size: contain;
```

And I have a div that I always want it to be in the center of the background image

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to keep the `.center` div in the center of the background image at all times? With CSS and/or JavaScript?

Or some other way to make an image responsive and have a div on the center at all times?

Code pen example https://codepen.io/brunolm/pen/GQxRVP

Comment: am hestating to close this one as you have high Rep :) can you clarify your needs ? as i understand this is a simple div centring and there is a lot of Dups questions

Comment: Simply centering the div vertically will not be enough, the image can get vertically/horizontally resized, and the center of the image might not be the same as the center of the div, does that make sense?

Comment: yes but the center of the image will always be the center of the centred div, no ? ... so if the div is centred and the background-image is also, i guess it's  enough

Comment: or maybe you can show us where it's not working ? and how it should work instead

Comment: If `.bg` width changes (to like `10px`) the height of the image will also change because `contain` keeps aspect ratio. But `.bg`'s height will not change (I only resized horizontally), so the center of the div is not the center of the image anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible, there is no way to retrieve the size on the background image resized by a modifier like `contain`.

## Responsive Image solution

Codepen

- Code https://codepen.io/brunolm/pen/rJdaGG?editors=1111
- Full View https://codepen.io/brunolm/full/rJdaGG/

So I decided to try to put the image with a `position: absolute` and the div I want to center also with an absolute positioning.

### Container

I can center elements by styling it with

```
align-items: center;
bottom: 0;
display: flex;
height: 100%;
justify-content: center;
left: 0;
position: relative;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

### Image

I can make the image responsive using

```
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
```

I can make it behave like a background by disabling selection

```
user-select: none;
```

I can center it with

```
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

### Centered div

I can center it with

```
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

### Calculate size

And to calculate the div size to be centered on the image

```
function doResize() {
  const img = document.getElementById('img');
  const center = document.getElementById('center');

  // img is responsive and width/height is available
  center.style.width = `${img.width * 0.5}px`;
  center.style.height = `${img.height * 0.65}px`;

  console.log(img.width, 'x', img.height);
}

// recalculate whenever the window size changes
window.addEventListener('resize', doResize);

// calculate initial size
doResize();
```

Comment: ok so the issue is to Resize not only center, this the part not hightlighted in the question ... as the center will always be the same but you want the div to also scale with the image

Answer (score -2):

`display: flex;`, `align-items: center;` and `margin: 0 auto;` are the keywords here.
To make the div high as the bg img is, use this example: https://codepen.io/phng/pen/PWEJGO. And then you could use position: absolute; to negate the padding on your second div.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ufo {
  background: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/404.svg') no-repeat center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.ufo div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="ufo">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your snippet the image doesn't have `background-size: contain`